# SSH key exchange configuration uncertainty

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm currently configuring ssh on a server and reading trough several guides.

Many feature a `@url.tld` after the option in `KexAlgorithms` like:

```
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

This is also mentioned, but not explained in the man pages.

My question is, what does the `@url.tld` do in the key exchange process and how does it affect it?

**edit:** I've found out that the SSH protocol allows custom algorithms which must be annotated using a `@domain`, resulting in the above mentioned `@libssh.org` at the end of the end of `curve25519-sha256`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It affects nothing; the `...@domain` syntax is just a common way to assign unique names without having to go through the bureaucracy of a central registry, and without accidentally using the same name as another project's incompatible implementation.

(One interesting example is the SSHv2 compression algorithms: `zlib` and `zlib@openssh.com` both mean the same DEFLATE/LZ77 algorithm, but the former is enabled immediately, while the latter merely indicates an agreement to enable `zlib` after authentication.

Another case is `aes256-cbc`, which used to be called `rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se` for a while.)